# How to search and replace each hit with a multiline register in which each hit is replaced with an individual line from the register?

Tags: search, replace

so if i have the following multiline text in my register `+`:

```
ZERO     
SIGN     
CARRY    
AUXILIARY
PARITY   
OVERFLOW 
INTERRUPT
DIRECTION
TRAP
```

And I have the following code:

```
case ZERO     :
  return a->FLAGS.derp;
case SIGN     :
  return a->FLAGS.derp;
case CARRY    :
  return a->FLAGS.derp;
case AUXILIARY:
  return a->FLAGS.derp;
case PARITY   :
  return a->FLAGS.derp;
case OVERFLOW :
  return a->FLAGS.derp;
case INTERRUPT:
  return a->FLAGS.derp;
case DIRECTION:
  return a->FLAGS.derp;
case TRAP     :
  return a->FLAGS.derp;
```

I want the result of a search and replace command (i.e. `:%s\derp\register+`\g) to be

```
case ZERO     :
  return a->FLAGS.ZERO;
case SIGN     :
  return a->FLAGS.SIGN;
case CARRY    :
  return a->FLAGS.CARRY;
case AUXILIARY:
  return a->FLAGS.AUXILIARY;
case PARITY   :
  return a->FLAGS.PARITY;
case OVERFLOW :
  return a->FLAGS.OVERFLOW;
case INTERRUPT:
  return a->FLAGS.INTERRUPT;
case DIRECTION:
  return a->FLAGS.DIRECTION;
case TRAP     :
  return a->FLAGS.TRAP;
```

The command `:%s/foo/\=@a/g` is very close to this but not close enough, it will insert the totality of the register on each match.

Comment: Do you mean where all the cases say "case derp" in your example?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using `:h sub-replace-expression` with the `list` flag of `getreg()`, assuming your code starts at line 1:

```
%s;derp;\=getreg('+',1,1)[float2nr((line('.')-1)/2)]
```

If your register looked like this (e.g., using a scratch buffer to duplicate lines):

```
ZERO     
ZERO     
SIGN     
SIGN     
CARRY  
CARRY   
&c...
```

this would simplify to

```
%s;derp;\=getreg('+',1,1)[line('.')]
```

which is a handy pattern in many situations.